# Property 'complete' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, ionic5, pull-to-refresh

In Ionic Vue, I am trying to use ion-refresher. According to the documentation, I should end with '`event.target.complete()`' but this gives me the following error: `Property 'complete' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'`.

What should I do, that is what the official documentation tells me. Thank you.

[https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/refresher](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **complete()** method is a method specific to the **ion-refresher** component in Ionic, so it will not be available on the **EventTarget** interface. To fix the error, you should make sure you are referencing the **ion-refresher** element correctly within your Vue component's template.

In your template, ensure you are using the correct event binding for the ionRefresh event, it should be like this:

```
<ion-refresher slot="fixed" @ionRefresh="onRefresh($event)">
</ion-refresher>
```

And in your script you should be able to do this:

```
methods: {
  onRefresh(event) {
    // perform your refresh logic here
    event.target.complete();
  }
}
```

**event.target** is the actual **ion-refresher** element in the DOM, and the complete() method is a method on that element that tells the **ion-refresher** to stop displaying the refreshing spinner.

Make sure that you have imported the **ion-refresher** component in your Vue file and also in your main.ts file for your Ionic Vue app.